# Проблема с оптимизацией производительности Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, производительность, долгая-загрузка

Здравствуйте,

у меня есть небольшой сайт-портфолио с несколькими страницами который открывается с огромной задержкой. Время межу тем, как сервер получает запрос на страницу и тем, как начал ее отдавать - 22-27 сек. На всех. И в админке тоже.

Размер самой страницы с картинками в среднем не превышает 1Мб.
Оперативной памяти занято не больше 30Мб.
Ни в логах сервера, ни в режиме отладки никаких явных ошибок не видно.
С WP Query тоже проблем не видно - среднее время запроса 50 ms.
Удаленных HTTP запросов и скриптов на другие сайты ни по дебагам, ни по логам не видно.
Плагины/темы отключены.

Куда еще смотреть?

Я уже сбилась с ног, а проблемма остается: каждую страничку на 2 картинки нужно ждать по полминуты.

Comment: я сталкивался с подобной ситуацией, когда сайт клиента был заражен вирусом. вирус обращался к внешнему сайту, но к тому времени внешний сайт уже сдох, браузер ждал данных с дохлого сайта и висел (пока не пройдет таймаут соединения). у вас очень похожая проблема. Попробуйте открыть консоль браузера и посмотреть, с какими хостами он пытается соединиться.

Comment: @strangeqargo, `Удаленных HTTP запросов и скриптов на другие сайты ни по дебагам, ни по логам не видно.`?

Comment: @Visman на сервер-сайде ни в логах ни в дебаге удаленных запросов и не будет. Они будут видны только в браузере (клиент-сайде), поскольку цель таких вирусов - заразить/отредиректить посетителя на другой сайт. Если автор сообщит, что проверил и бразуерные логи тоже, то моя гипотеза, конечно, отпадет.

Comment: @Natala, ссылку на ваш сайт покажите.

Comment: @Visman сайт: http://jenya-marchenko.com/

Comment: @Natala про браузер был не прав. что-то на сервере. простейший дебаг - вставьте строчку типа `if isset($_GET["sodebug"]){die("debug");}`  в начало самое начало index.php, откройте сайт в браузере с парамтером ?sodebug=1. если сразу сдохнет, значит проблемы ниже по скрипту, если не сдохнет, проблемы хостера

Comment: скорее всего проблема с размерами изображений и плагином isotope/portfolio. на сервер-сайде он обходит картинки, считает их размеры, тупит.